# Extjs - Retrieve xtype using custom config

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have defined an xtype:

```
Ext.define('Sample.view.CustomTextfield', {
  extend: 'Ext.field.Text',
  customConfig: 'foo'
  . . . .
});
```

I want to now if there is a method to create a component using the `customConfig`.

doing something like `myPanel.add(Ext.getComponentByConfig('customConfig', 'foo'));`

Is there an extjs to do so?

**NOTE:**

The custom component is not yet rendered but is already defined so answers using `ComponentQuery` and the like (`.up()`, `.down()`, etc..) is incorrect.

**EDIT**:

Here's a sample use-case:

Supposedly you have an array of object key-value pairs:

```
var myArray = [
  { config: 'customConfig', value: 'foo' },
  { config: 'anotherCustomConfig', value: 'bar' },
  . . . .
]
```

Now, what I need to do is to loop over the array and retrieve the `config` property which I will then use to retrieve the xtype that has that config with a value equal to `value`, i.e, for config `customConfig` with a value `foo`. In short, I want to dynamically render views using an array of `config->value` objects.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, please see edit

Comment: Still doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What part of my question doesn't make sense to you? could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's whay I came up with. I don't know if this is the right way to do it but I will share this anyway. Please feel free to improve this:

```
Ext.createBy = function (config, value) {
    var classes = Ext.ClassManager.classes;
    for (var cls in classes) {
        if (classes.hasOwnProperty(cls)) {
            var c = classes[cls];
            if ((c[config] && c[config] === value) || (c.prototype && c.prototype[config] && c.prototype[config] === value)) {
                return Ext.create(classes[cls].getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this function, `Ext.createBy` does is iterate over the classes which are held by `Ext.ClassManager` and check if the class has a `config` and value supplied in the parameters. Then it calls `Ext.create` using the which passed the tests.

This can be used like this:

`myPanel.add(Ext.createBy('someConfig', 'someValue'));`

or, pertaining my sample use-case:

```
var myArray = [
  { config: 'customConfig', value: 'foo' },
  { config: 'anotherCustomConfig', value: 'bar' },
  . . . .
];

for (var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++) {
   var obj = myArray[i];
   myPanel.add(Ext.createBy(obj.config, obj.value);
}
```

This will dynamically add items to `myPanel` depending on the `config->value`.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to add a custom component to a panel you can use alias property in Ext.define and use the widget name to add it.

```
 Ext.define('Sample.view.CustomTextfield', {
  extend: 'Ext.field.Text',
  alias: 'widget.foo'
  . . . .
});
```

In myPanel, add this component like,

```
myPanel.add({ xtype :'foo',});
```

Comment: i already know that but what I need is instantiating the component using only the `customConfig`

Comment: which extjs version are you using?

Comment: my post is tagged `extjs4.2`.. 4.2.1 to be exact